# Vue component not mounting or rendering and no error messages

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following 2 components

**BrewTitle.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Brew Title"
    };
  },
  created() {
    console.log("title created")
  }
};
</script>
```

**Snackbar.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Brew Title"
    };
  },
    created() {
        console.log("snackbar created")
    }
};
</script>
```

How they are added to the index.js file

```
import Vue from "vue";

import BrewTitle from "./components/BrewTitle";
import Snackbar from "./components/Snackbar";

Vue.component("brewtitle", BrewTitle);
Vue.component("snackbar", Snackbar);

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

In my html template I have the following snippet

```
<div id="app">
<brewtitle />
<snackbar />
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

The components are almost identical, but the snackbar is nowhere to be found on the html page or in the view browser extension. There are no problems with webpack and there is no message in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see either of the _"... created"_ console messages?

Comment: There is no message in the console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers don't support self-closing tags like these:

```html
<brewtitle />
<snackbar />
```

Try having explicit closing tags instead:

```html
<brewtitle></brewtitle>
<snackbar></snackbar>
```

If you use a self-closing tag for a component then the browser will just treat it as an opening tag. An implicit closing tag will be created when the parent element closes. That'll work fine if there are no other siblings but it will go wrong when there are.

So taking your original code as an example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <brewtitle />
  <snackbar />
</div>
```

The `<brewtitle>` won't count as closed until it reaches the closing `</div>`. So this is equivalent to:

```html
<div id="app">
  <brewtitle>
    <snackbar></snackbar>
  </brewtitle>
</div>
```

So `<snackbar>` will be treated as a child of `<brewtitle>`. As `brewtitle` doesn't have a slot the `snackbar` will just be discarded.

This only applies if the HTML is being parsed directly by the browser. For anything parsed by Vue itself, such as in your `.vue` files, this won't be a problem.

From the official Vue documentation, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

> Components with no content should be self-closing in single-file components, string templates, and JSX - but never in DOM templates.
>
> ...
>
> Unfortunately, HTML doesn’t allow custom elements to be self-closing - only official “void” elements.

Comment: OP says only one of the components is not rendering. Also, you're incorrect about self-closing tags ~ https://jsfiddle.net/k51n7dgo/

Comment: skirtle I've added other components to the HTML file using the same approach. They all render as expected.

Comment: @Phil Try to put two `<snackbar/>` components next to each other and you'll find it doesn't work. If you use `<snackbar></snackbar>` instead then it works fine.

Comment: @kristiannissen I have extended my answer to explain why it sometimes appears to work and sometimes doesn't.